# Right way to authorize robot to read Google Sheets

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

I have to create a bot that reads some data from private Google Spreadsheet. Is there any way to permanently authorize bot to read it? The bot should be daemonized.

While reading the quickstart (https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/python) example I found that OAuth2 flow requires user to authorize, but it is not acceptable because the daemon should work in background.

Second option that I found is Service account key, but it is not acceptable for private docs.

Is there any way to do it right?

Comment: The best way I found is to use authorization from keyfile and share the document for application's email